# Error while subtracting 2 date columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a function to get random dates..

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import random

def dates(start_date, end_date):
    start_date = date(start_date[0], start_date[1], start_date[2])
    end_date = date(end_date[0], end_date[1], end_date[2])
    
    days_delta = (end_date - start_date).days
    
    return start_date + timedelta(days=random.randrange(days_delta))


df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(100))

df['MOVE_OUT_DATE'] = date(9999, 12, 31)
df['MOVE_IN_DATE'] = [dates((2021, 1, 1), (2021, 6, 30)) for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
```

To get the difference in days I do this,

`df['days_diff'] = df['MOVE_OUT_DATE'] - df['MOVE_IN_DATE']`

and this works fine in **VS Code**. But it throws a "Python int too large to convert to C long" in **Databricks**. A screenshot of error is attached below,
[image]

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, your current code is not giving a DataFrame

Comment: My apologies, there were some syntax errors. I've corrected it now. Could you try once again please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get everything to work and I believe it is what you are trying to accomplish with your code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-06-01', freq = 'D'), columns = ['START_DATE'])
df['MOVE_OUT_DATE'] = '2260-12-31'
df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'])
df['MOVE_OUT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MOVE_OUT_DATE'])
df['DAYS_DIFF'] = df['MOVE_OUT_DATE'] - df['START_DATE']
df
```

However, if you notice the 'MOVE_OUT_DATE' is only set to 2060 as anything long than that produced an error as the being to long. Could you take this and generate the results you want (if you converted it into a function)?

Comment: No problem, if the answer worked for you please selected "answered" and upvote so others know that it is the correct answer for similar questions.

Comment: I'd love to but I don't have enough reputation to upvote. I'll do that once I have enough of the reputation points.

Comment: Don't worry about it if you can't upvote you can still accept the post as an answer.